# jQuery class change based on scroll ignoring last section

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing, scroll, nav

I'm using jQuery to guide my pages scrolling and change the color of a  nav item to correspond to the section you're in. Everything's working well, but the script is ignoring the last section on the page (Contact).

This is largely based on another question here on Stack, but I've modified the code to fit my needs and then ran into the issue.

Test site:
http://dev4.dhut.ch/

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#music" title="Music">MUSIC</a></li>
        <li><a href="#photos" title="Photos">PHOTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#lyrics" title="Lyrics">LYRICS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news" title="News">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#info" title="Info">INFO</a></li>
        <li><a href='#contact' title="Contact">CONTACT</a></li>
    </ul>
    <span></span>
</nav>
```

JavaScript:

```
var $sections    = $('section'),
    $navs        = $('nav > ul > li'),
    topsArray    = $sections.map(function(){
                       return $(this).position().top - 100;
                   }).get(),
    len          = topsArray.length,
    currentIndex = 0,
    getCurrent   = function(top){
                       for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
                           if(top > topsArray[i] && topsArray[i+1] && top < topsArray[i+1]){
                               return i;
                           }
                       }
                   };

$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var scrollTop  = $(this).scrollTop(),
        checkIndex = getCurrent( scrollTop );

    if( checkIndex !== currentIndex ){
        currentIndex = checkIndex;
        $navs.eq( currentIndex ).addClass('active').siblings('.active').removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: It's a little scary that this is *exactly* my problem and *exactly* the same elements and class names. o.o

Comment: Sounds like we got it from the same place :) check out twitter bootstrap- they've got a killer plugin called ScrollSpy that does this way better. There's also a project on Github that combines it with in-page scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following line is where the problem lies:

```
if(top > topsArray[i] && topsArray[i+1] && top < topsArray[i+1]){
```

Specifically `topsArray[i+1]` is undefined for the last iteration of `i`. Try pushing one more value into topsArray that includes the height of the entire page.

```
topsArray = $sections.map(function(){
               return $(this).position().top - 100;
            }).get(),
topsArray.push(document.height);
```